# I have yet to see the results

Tags: adverbs

> I have yet to see the results.

What does this sentence mean? I can understand it without "yet". But with "yet", it puzzles me. Does it mean

> I haven't yet seen the results.

If it does, how can it mean that? "Yet" means up to the present. *I have yet to see the results.* = *I have to see the results up to the present.* But the latter doesn't make sense. How does the sentence mean *I haven't yet seen the results*?

Comment: Yes. That is the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English isn't logical, and "yet" can have a negative meaning in a few contexts. This is an idiomatic use of yet, Cambridge considers it an idiom "[have yet to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yet#:%7E:text=%C2%A0-,have%20yet%20to,-C2) + infinitive" and the meaning of the idiom is that you haven't done it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "yet" is **not** illogical here. You can understand it as:

> I have **yet (still)** [been waiting] to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

"I have yet to see the results" is parsable as "Up to this date, I wait to see the results."